# Execute Multiple functions in a function

Tags: javascript, function

```
function executeActions(param)
{
    if((param != undefined) && (param.length > 0))
    {
        for(i=0; i < param.length; i++)
        {
            //eval like function
            param[i]();
        }
    }
}

function clearFields()
{
    ...
}

function showAbs(param)
{
    if(param ==  'insert')
    {
        ...
    }
    else if(param  == 'update')
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}

$("#clearButton").click(function(event)
{
    //var functions = ["clearFields()","showAbs('insert')"];

    var a = showAbs('insert');
    var functions = [clearFields, a];

    executeActions(functions);
});
```

Hello everyone!
How can I execute some functions with parameters in a row in a set of instructions like i've showed above?

If they don't have any parameters, then the functions execute like in chain, but, if one or more of them uses 
some parameters, it stops with the error: "param[i] is not a function".

Maybe if you have another elegant solution for this code, i'd appreciate if you share with us.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Storing all functions in array and executing them at end doesn't seem like good practice.

Comment: Because I have a huge set of functions, that are needed in some part of my code, and it repeats itlself along other tiny parts, so i need to it once and in an organized way, so i'v thought about that, what do you think about ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial application for this. Partial application means that you take a given function and fix one or more parameters to it. Example

```
function sum(a, b){
    return a + b;
}

function product(a, b){
    return a * b;
}

function doSomething(){
    // do something
}

function runFunctions(funcs){
    for(var i = 0;i<funcs.length;i++){
        funcs[i]();
    }
}


var mySum = function(){
    return sum(5, 6);
}

var myProduct = function(){
    return product(2, 3);
}

runFunctions(mySum, myProduct, doSomething);
```

The above is using ES 5 syntax. You could make this a bit more concise using ES 6 syntax:

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
const product = (a, b) => a * b;
const doSomething = () => // do something


const runFunctions = funcs => {
    for(func of funcs)
        func();
}


var mySum = () => sum(5, 6);
var myProduct = () => product(2, 3);

runFunctions(mySum, myProduct, doSomething);
```

or you could use the `bind` function to take care of fixing the vars:

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
const product = (a, b) => a * b;
const doSomething = () => // do something


const runFunctions = funcs => {
    for(func of funcs)
        func();
}

runFunctions(sum.bind(null, 5,6), myProduct.bind(null, 2,3), doSomething);
```

Comment: You can use `Function.prototype.bind` instead of a thunk.

Comment: True, various ways to skin this. You could also create a special apply function, but I like the bind better

Answer (score 0):

For me a way you want to achieve may be not readable for other developers.
You may create a function that will group all your function executions like:

```
function groupedFunctions{
    return {
       A: funcA(param),
       B: funcB(param),
       C: funcC(param)
    }
}

function executeActions(funcObj, params) {
   funcObj.A(params.a);
   funcObj.B(params.b);
}

let params = {a: 1, b:2}
executeActions(groupedFunction(), params)
```

Comment: Why you need to loop functions?

Comment: Because I have a huge set of functions, that are needed in some part of my code, and it repeats itlself along other tiny parts, so i need to it once and in an organized way, so i'v thought about that, what  do you think about ?